# spring hadoop : unable to set the configuration getting Found ambiguous parameter type

Tags: spring, hadoop

I  was trying to create a util class for performing Hadoop copy in Spring XD, I defined configuration as below

```
<int:channel id="input"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="input" ref="utilhandler" />
<bean id="utilhandler" class="com.test.hadoop.HadoopUtil"/>
<hdp:configuration  register-url-handler="false" properties-location="${xd.config.home}/hadoop.properties" >
    fs.defaultFS=${fsUri}

</hdp:configuration>
</beans>
```

below is the snippet bean class 
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
public class HadoopUtil implements InitializingBean{

```
      private String destinationDir;
private FsShell shell;
      @Autowired
private Configuration configuration;
public Configuration getHadoopConfiguration()
{
    return configuration;
}
```

when I execute, I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactor
yBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lan
g.Void] for method match: [public org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration com.test.hadoop.HadoopUtil.getHadoopConfiguration(), public void com.test.hadoop.HadoopUtil.setConfiguration(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to define setter and getter method for property `configuration`
Please test with this and let us know it works or need more help